# Python Knapsack Problem with fixed number of elements

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, combinatorics, knapsack-problem

So far I have the following code which I believe selects up to a MAX of 4 (or n) elements in the knapsack (hence the 3rd dimension). However, I want to ensure that the code ALWAYS selects 4 (or n) elements. Can someone please advise as I can't find anything about this anywhere...

```
def knapsack2(n, weight, count, values, weights):
    dp = [[[0] * (weight + 1) for _ in range(n + 1)] for _ in range(count + 1)]
    for z in range(1, count + 1):
        for y in range(1, n + 1):
            for x in range(weight + 1):
                if weights[y - 1] <= x:
                    dp[z][y][x] = max(dp[z][y - 1][x],
                                      dp[z - 1][y - 1][x - weights[y - 1]] + values[y - 1])
                else:
                    dp[z][y][x] = dp[z][y - 1][x]

    return dp[-1][-1][-1]

w = 10
k = 4
values = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2]
weights = [4, 5, 1, 1, 1]
n = len(values)

# find elements in 
elements=[]
dp=m
while (n> 0):
    if dp[k][n][w] - dp[k][n-1][w - weights[n-1]] == values[n-1]:
        #the element 'n' is in the knapsack
        elements.append(n)
        n = n-1 #//only in 0-1 knapsack
        w -= weights[n]
    else: 
        n = n-1
```

Comment: Check out: [Knapsack Problem with exact required item number constraint](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/123553/knapsack-problem-with-exact-required-item-number-constraint)

Comment: I have no idea how to apply that to my code...